# Can't install Jinja2 on Mac

Tags: linux, macos, unix, terminal, jinja2

When I run a python file that imports Jinja2, and I think I've installed Jinja2 properly, but I get this error:

```
    import jinja2
ImportError: No module named jinja2
```

Some people online suggest that I should do this:
pip install Jinja2

but this is what I get, which I think means that I already have Jinja2 installed on my machine.

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Jinja2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.9.dev-py2.7.egg
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): MarkupSafe in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MarkupSafe-0.23-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg (from Jinja2)
```

Does anyone know what I should do?

Comment: What's your python version? What happens when you do : pip install --upgrade --user jinja2 ?

Comment: `No module named jinja2` : No module by name  jinja2 is installed with  Jinja2. .....  Examples v2.9  https://github.com/django/django → → →    https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/template/backends -

Comment: @khrm This is what I get: Requirement already up-to-date: jinja2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.9.dev-py2.7.egg
Requirement already up-to-date: MarkupSafe in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MarkupSafe-0.23-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg (from jinja2)

Comment: I want python version. Did you install python using brew?

Comment: @khrm It was preinstalled on my mac. I have Python 2.7.10

Comment: How did you install pip?

Comment: @khrm I really don't remember. I searched online to install Jinja2 on mac and I did everything I found on the internet. It was probably one of the commands on the internet. If I remember correctly, it was maybe something like easyinstall.

Comment: Try using brew version. I couldn't recreate this.

Comment: @khrm okay. I don't know why this is taking so long. I will try that. Thank you so much for your help. I will let you know once I figure it out.

Comment: @khrm It was the problem with my app.yaml. I should've included the libraries for jinja2 in app.yaml file. Thank you for your help